# Bind column to multiplication of other columns

Tags: javafx

I would like to bind amount column to price and quantity columns such that everytime either quantity or price, amount updates.

```
    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
    import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
    import javafx.event.EventHandler;
    import javafx.geometry.Insets;
    import javafx.scene.Group;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.control.Label;
    import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
     import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.CellEditEvent;
     import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
     import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
     import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTableCell;
     import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
     import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
     import javafx.scene.text.Font;
     import javafx.stage.Stage;
     import javafx.util.converter.NumberStringConverter;

   /**
    *
    * @author Yunus
    */
public class ColumnBinding  extends Application{
   private TableView<Product> table = new TableView<Product>();
   private final ObservableList<Product> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
   final HBox hb = new HBox();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());
    primaryStage.setTitle("Book Store Sample");
    primaryStage.setWidth(650);
    primaryStage.setHeight(550);

    final Label label = new Label("Testing");
    label.setFont(new Font("Arial", 20));

    table.setEditable(true);

    TableColumn priceCol = new TableColumn("Price");
    priceCol.setMinWidth(100);
    priceCol.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<Product, String>("price"));
    priceCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.<Product, Number>forTableColumn(new NumberStringConverter()));
    priceCol.setOnEditCommit(
            new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Product, Number>>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(CellEditEvent<Product, Number> t) {
                    ((Product) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                            t.getTablePosition().getRow())
                    ).setPrice(t.getNewValue().intValue());
                }
            }
    );

    TableColumn quantityCol = new TableColumn("Quantity");
    quantityCol.setMinWidth(200);
    quantityCol.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<Product, Number>("quantity"));
    quantityCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.<Product, Number>forTableColumn(new NumberStringConverter()));
    quantityCol.setOnEditCommit(
            new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Product, Number>>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(CellEditEvent<Product, Number> t) {
                    ((Product) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                            t.getTablePosition().getRow())
                    ).setQuantity(t.getNewValue().intValue());
                }
            }
    );

    TableColumn amount = new TableColumn("Amount");
    amount.setMinWidth(200);
    amount.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<Product, String>("amount"));

    data.addAll(new Product(10, 12, 120),
                new Product(20, 12, 240),
                new Product(30, 12, 360),
                new Product(40, 12, 480),
                new Product(50, 12, 600));
    table.setItems(data);
    table.getColumns().addAll(priceCol, quantityCol, amount);
    final VBox vbox = new VBox();
    vbox.setSpacing(5);
    vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10, 0, 0, 10));
    vbox.getChildren().addAll(label, table, hb);

    ((Group) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().addAll(vbox);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static class Product{
    Product(){}

    public Product(float quantity, float price, float amount) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.price = price;
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    private float quantity;
    private float price;
    private float amount;

    public float getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(float quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public float getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(float price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public float getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(float amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }


}
 }
```

The challenge though is not to change POJO class(Product) with property fields

Comment: "The challenge though is not to change POJO class with property fields". Why? Why restrict yourself from using the API specifically provided for the purpose you intend?

Comment: Because i will have to change many other places in the source code i guess, as i use constructor without parameters and property values needs to initialized on constructor

Comment: Why would you need to change anything else? The only public methods would still be there and would still have exactly the same functionality (which is kind of the point of how the JavaFX Property pattern was designed).

Comment: could use suggest what i need to change in my POJO and still maintain unparametized construct

Comment: Just do the obvious. I supplied an answer using that approach. Note though that your class makes no sense really, because if `amount` is dependent on `quantity` and `price`, having a constructor parameter for `amount` and a `setAmount` method doesn't make any sense. I removed those in the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would just use JavaFX properties in the model class. Then you can establish the relationship by binding in the model:

```
public static class Product{

    private final FloatProperty quantity  = new SimpleFloatProperty();
    private final FloatProperty price  = new SimpleFloatProperty();
    private final ReadOnlyFloatWrapper amount  = new ReadOnlyFloatWrapper();

    Product(){
        this(0f, 0f);
    }

    // if amount is supposed to depend on quantity and price, it makes
    // no sense at all to have a constructor taking parameters for all 
    // three values...
    public Product(float quantity, float price) {
        setQuantity(quantity);
        setPrice(price);
        this.amount.bind(this.quantity.multiply(this.price));
    }

    public float getQuantity() {
        return quantityProperty().get();
    }

    public void setQuantity(float quantity) {
        quantityProperty().set(quantity);
    }

    public FloatProperty quantityProperty() {
        return quantity ;
    }

    public float getPrice() {
        return priceProperty().get();
    }

    public void setPrice(float price) {
        priceProperty().set(price);
    }

    public FloatProperty priceProperty() {
        return price ;
    }

    public float getAmount() {
        return amountProperty.get();
    }

    // Again, it makes no sense at all to have this method
    // if amount depends on the other values
    // public void setAmount(float amount) {
    //     this.amount = amount;
    // }

    public ReadOnlyFloatProperty amountProperty() {
        return amount.getReadOnlyProperty();
    }

}
```

Now your table columns are easy:

```
TableColumn<Product, Float> priceColumn = new TableColumn<>("Price");
priceColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().priceProperty().asObject());

TableColumn<Product, Float> quantityColumn = new TableColumn<>("Quantity");
quantityColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().quantityProperty().asObject());

TableColumn<Product, Float> amountColumn = new TableColumn<>("Amount");
amountColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().amountProperty().asObject());
```

Comment: That solved my problem, but I would like to know how this code: `this.amount.bind(this.quantity.multiply(this.price));` move to `setCellValueFactory` to bind.